# Passing a username object from API call to a second API call with handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two APIs, the first API call to fetch an array of accounts with usernames/objects. The username/object will get passed to the second API call to deactivate the individual account. A button will handle the second API call to deactivate the account.

Currently, the error I have all of the usernames/objects are being passed together to the second call and not individually.

```
const [activeAccounts, setActiveAccounts] = useState([])

const [deactivateUsername, setDeactivateUsername] = useState({
    username: '',
})

useEffect(() => {

    const ActiveAccountsApi = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/user/admin/account/active')
    const data = await res.json()
    setActiveAccounts(data)
    console.log(data)
   }

   const accountUsername = activeAccounts.map(acc => acc.username)
   const user = accountUsername.map(single => single)
   setDeactivateUsername({ username: user })

}, [])

const DeactivateAccountsApi = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/admin/account/deactivate/${deactivateUsername.username}`)
    const data = await res.json()   
}

//button will handle this - will remove the item from the returned list and should handle 
 the second API call/request to deactivate the account with the username object being passed

const handleRemoveItem = idx => {
    const newAccount = [...activeAccounts]
    newAccount.splice(idx, 1)
    setActiveAccounts(newAccount)
    DeactivateAccountsApi()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const accountUsername = activeAccounts.map(acc => acc.username)
const user = accountUsername.map(single => single)
```

The second line is giving you the exact same result as the previous, and it will result in you passing the full list of usernames. It's not clear what the criteria is for pulling which specific name you want out of that list, but ultimately that's what you'll need to here e.g.

```
setDeactivateUsername({ username: accountUsername[0] }) // set the first username as an example
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any idea how to loop through the index [0], [1], [2]...etc ?
This is the answer to my question only If I can make it work lol. 
I look forward to hearing from you. Best

Comment: @LondonCreative what do you mean? Your state can only have one object set at a time, why do you want to loop through it? To find a specific one?

Comment: thank you I've managed to fix it and it is working as it should. Thanks for your help though. Best